# Xamarin iOS Binding Library Native Framework's Bundles Not Recognized in the Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

In my Xamarin.iOS application, I referenced my binding library which is have 4 objective-c framework in it. Two of the frameworks use bundle files for verification. Xamarin.iOS recognize one of them but not the other. I placed .bundles in the Resources folder as a folder and set the build action as BundleResources but nothing change. After that I tried with the root folder but results is the same. So in the native framework, bundle called like this:

```
NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class];
NSString *resourceBundlePath = [frameworkBundle pathForResource:@"FrameworkName" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSBundle *resourceBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:resourceBundlePath];
NSString *myPath = [resourceBundle pathForResource:@"somefile" ofType:nil];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
NSString *myInfo = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

What is the equivalent of this in the Xamarin.iOS world?

PS: I tried to add bundles in binding project also but no luck.

Comment: You want to convert those objective-c code to c#?

Comment: No, I want to understand which path is this bundle should be located in visual studio for mac. Because neither root nor Resources works. Framework get the file like above code.

Comment: I never see such bundle in visual-studio. Does another framework has this bundle? Do you mean [Linking the dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries?tabs=windows#linking-the-dependencies)?

Comment: No, native framework call the bundle with self.class, so in the Xamarin.iOS app where to put the bundle folder? Because if it calls from the MainBundle resources folder should work i think.

Comment: Hi @JackHua-MSFT I just found out the libraries are statics. So they didn't added in the app bundle. How the framework see it's bundle then? Can you help?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how the framework see it's bundle. I just think those objective-c codes should not appear in xamarin.forms project. The normal usage is add the library .dll and reference it to the project.

Comment: When you include those frameworks do you embed them?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yes objective codes doesn’t appear in the xamarin side. I just shared to show how library use it.

Comment: @skaak since they are static they couldn’t embedded in the app bundle.

Comment: Ok - don't know Xamarin sorry, just a shot in the dark ...

Comment: @skaak in the above code, where the app look for the bundle? Not the main bundle right?

Comment: So two are static and those two uses bundle and just one work? And both use the same code - that code that you provided?

Comment: @skaak no I don’t have other one’s code but it can access the bundle resource located in the app bundle. But the one with the above code failed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223103/discussion-between-skaak-and-tugce-arar).